# $.post or $. ajax post in c# .net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, .post

I have implemented the  following $.Post Jquery function in my asp.net page MAIN Page.aspx
the

```
$.post({ url: "MAIN Page.aspx",
         data: { "Status":ddl },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                });
```

where ddl is my data to be posted ...i have placed this $.post in the document.ready() and i tried accessing the posted value in the code behind as

```
var status= Request.Form.Get["Status"]...
```

but when i run the code the value of the status is null..

please help and guide if i am correct in my implementation of the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.post('MAIN Page.aspx', { status: ddl }, function(result) {
    alert('success');
});
```

and on your server:

```
var status= Request.Form["Status"];
```

Also you haven't shown what this `ddl` javascript variable is and how you assigned it a value but make sure that it is not a complex object but it contains some simple type.

Alternatively if you want to use the `$.ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'MAIN Page.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { status: ddl },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('result');
    }
});
```

Comment: And how more specifically did you obtain this value? Did you use the `.val()` function?

Comment: @IamTheBoss  Also you mentioned _"i have placed this $.post in the document.ready()"_ - so it's fired onload(?), and not really _"obtained from dropdown list"_ - which is pretty much similar to what Darin D is pointing out

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes i used .val() inside ready() to get the value of ddl

Comment: @EdSF i have placed $.post as the last statement in my script

Comment: @IamTheBoss it doesn't matter where in the _.ready()_ script you put it. It's the proper _event_ you need to "hook" into. You have to either hook the POST to your submit, or onchange of the dropdown. If I'm understanding your post/comments correctly, the event fires only onload of page which is what _.ready()_ is. At no other time/event is that call made. If this is accurate, you can debug the method that is called and see _when_ it is called to check/verify.

Comment: @EdSF that really sorted my problem